# hokuyo_node, where to install with Groovy?

Tags: ros, beaglebone, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working to get the hokuyo_node running on an embedded system (arm based BeagleBone). The ROS distribution on the Beagle is Groovy but the Hokuyo_node tutorial references Fuerte (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode).

I know the laser_driver was installed under opt/ros/fuerte/stacks in ROS Fuerte but the install locations for ROS are different in Groovy. Should the hokuyo_node go in the ros_ws, the ros_catkin_ws, or somewhere else?

Also, can just the hokuyo_node be installed and not the full laser_driver package or would this require some editing of the pathways somewhere in the hokuyo_node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63080/hokuyo_node,-where-to-install-with-groovy?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably install the Fuerte version in the corresponding Groovy location: **/opt/ros/groovy/stacks**.

It is generally safer to install all of a stack, in case there are inter-dependencies. If you are short of space, you can experiment with individual packages.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-20**:
In the Groovy install there is no /opt/ros/groovy/stacks directory. Everything is in the Home directory in either ros_catkin_ws or ros_ws. Should the laser_driver stack go into one of these (maybe with some edits for pathways in the ??? files) to fit with the new ROS build environment?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-20**:
That's probably because all the packages you installed so far were converted to catkin, which no longer uses the **stacks/** directory. Just create it and put the hokuyu_node there.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-20**:
Maybe I misunderstood your original question, which seemed to imply you were installing to /opt/ros. If you are using source workspaces, just put hokuyu_node in the rosbuild workspace, not catkin.

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-21**:
Thanks for all the help. I found the install process at http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin and got the laser_driver stack installed in the rosbuild workspace.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki referenced was old; as [I added updated info](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode?action=diff&rev2=28&rev1=27) just now, [hokuyo_node](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/) is installable via `apt` as noted in the updated wiki.

Also note that [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node/) package is recommended instead of `hokuyo_node`, as written in the wiki as well.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1